# The time complexity of doing O(h) algorithm n times

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

What is the time complexity of doing O(h) algorithm when h is the height of the node in BST n times (the number of elements in the tree) , I believe it's O(n) and not O(n*h) but I have no clue how to prove it.

The specific algorithm that works in O(h) is finding the In-order predecessor of an element in BST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost of computing inorder successors n times in any BST is O(n). To see this, count how many times you touch each edge in the tree. You’ll pass down the edge once when you first explore a subtree, and once more after you leave it. Overall, this means you touch each edge at most twice, so the total work done is O(n).

Note that generally speaking you can upper-bound the cost of performing n O(h)-time on a BST that has height h at O(hn), and that will never underestimate things. However, if you know more specifically about the algorithm you’re using, as in this case, you can get a tighter bound.

Answer (score 1):

**O(n²)**.

A binary search tree is not balanced, which means that the height of a node can be equal to the number of nodes of the tree, hence O(n²).

Comment: While in general doing O(h) work O(n) times can be upper-bounded at O(n^2), in this specific case that bound is loose and can be tightened.

Comment: Depends on the approach of the algorithm. The algorithms themselves can, truly, be bound to O(n). But what if the only information of the tree you have is the root? Then finding each of the nodes would take O(h) unless you are given the reference to the node itself or you store this reference, and this is not very common. AFAIK, finding the node is a requirement before you find its predecessor.

Comment: You’re correct that beginning at the root and searching down is going to take a long time. If you begin your search from the previously-discovered node rather than the root of the tree, the search is much faster.